# How large is a DWORD with 32- and 64-bit code?

Tags: c++, winapi, 64-bit, dword

In Visual C++ a DWORD is just an unsigned long that is machine, platform, and SDK dependent.  However, since DWORD is a double word (that is 2 * 16), is a DWORD still 32-bit on 64-bit architectures?

Comment: A a DWORD is not machine, platform, nor SDK dependent.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Actually, on 32-bit computers a word is 32-bit, but the DWORD type is a leftover from the good old days of 16-bit.

In order to make it easier to port programs to the newer system, Microsoft has decided all the old types will not change size.

You can find the official list here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(VS.85).aspx

All the platform-dependent types that changed with the transition from 32-bit to 64-bit end with _PTR (DWORD_PTR will be 32-bit on 32-bit Windows and 64-bit on 64-bit Windows).

Comment: The actual ranges are listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx).

Comment: @LaurieStearn I think this article is about the data types that the Microsoft compilers use internally, not the winapi data types like `DWORD`.

Comment: Yeah, the article in the answer's linked [official list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751(VS.85).aspx) now has the ranges: Quote: **DWORD: A 32-bit unsigned integer. The range is 0 through 4294967295 decimal.**

Comment: DWORD is on the windows libraries equal to an "unsigned long"

Answer (score 18):

It is defined as:

```
typedef unsigned long       DWORD;
```

However, according to the MSDN:

> On 32-bit platforms, long is
>   synonymous with int.

Therefore, DWORD is 32bit on a 32bit operating system. There is a separate define for a 64bit DWORD:

```
typdef unsigned _int64 DWORD64;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 12):

No ... on all Windows platforms DWORD is 32 bits. LONGLONG or LONG64 is used for 64 bit types.

Comment: it has nothing to do with Windows, it's Intel term

Comment: @Abyx: the typedef `DWORD` is very Windows.

Comment: @rubenvb, oh and why it's called `DWORD` and not something else like `QBYTE` or `DUBWD`?

Answer (score 1):

Windows API defines DWORD sizes as follows:

- **x86:** sizeof(DWORD) = **4**
- **x64:** sizeof(DWORD) = **4**