# bool pointer from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, boolean, dllimport

I want to use a function in a C++ DLL in my C# application using DLLImport:

```
BOOL IsEmpty( DWORD KeyID, BOOL *pFlag )
```

I tried many combinations but in vain, like:

```
public extern static bool IsEmpty(int KeyID, ref bool pFlag);
```

The method returns false (that means an error).

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Minor note, `DWORD` is an unsigned 32-bit type.  The corresponding type in C# is `uint`, not `int`.

Comment: bool is the standard C++ type. BOOL is a MFC type. they are not the same.

Comment: public extern static int IsEmpty(int KeyID, ref int pFlag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help!

finally this works for me

public extern static int IsEmpty(
            int KeyID,
            int[] pFlag)

Answer (score 4):

To [quote "Willy"](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/big-c-boolean-t1343763.html) (with amendments):

> Beware the booleans!
>
> Win32 defines different versions of booleans.
>
> 1) BOOL used by most Win32 API's, is <strike>an unsigned int</strike> [a signed int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) (4 bytes)
>
> 2) BOOLEAN is a single byte, only used by a few win32 API's!!
>
> 3) and C/C++ has it's builtin 'bool' which is a single byte

...and to add what @tenfour pointed out:

> 4) the even more bizarre VARIANT_BOOL

```
typedef short VARIANT_BOOL;
#define VARIANT_TRUE ((VARIANT_BOOL)-1)
#define VARIANT_FALSE ((VARIANT_BOOL)0)
```

The signed or unsigned nature shouldn't matter for BOOL, as the only "false" pattern is 0.  So try treating it as a 4 byte quantity...however you interface with a DWORD [may be satisfactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419/visual-c-how-large-is-a-dword-with-32-and-64-bit-code), (I've not dealt with Windows 64-bit conventions.)

Comment: I don't believe that the size of BOOL nor DWORD changes on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: I'd add the even more bizarre `VARIANT_BOOL` where `VARIANT_FALSE` is -1.

Answer (score 1):

`BOOL` in Win32 is a typedef of int, so you should just change `bool` to `Int32`, so the definition is `int IsEmpty(uint KeyID, ref int pFlag)`

Answer (score 1):

because in c++ BOOL is defined as int. You should use

```
    [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern  bool IsEmpty(uint KeyID, ref int pFlag) ;
```

Comment: To be more precise: BOOL is defined inside the Win32 API header files (not any C++ standard, though C++ added a `bool` that did not exist in C).  MSDN does however say it's a [signed int from WinDef.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx)...not an unsigned as from the source I quoted.  Although signed/unsigned technically should not matter as only 0 is FALSE and that has the same bit pattern regardless.  :-/