# Using ReadProcess function of kernel32.dll at pascal

Tags: dll, pascal

I override the function library kernel32.dll in Pascal and OpenProcess function returns 0. Function GetLastError() returns 87 error, that means

> ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
>   87 (0x57)
>   The parameter is incorrect.

What could be wrong?

```
Program UODll;
const search_window = 'Ultima Online - xxx (The Abyss)';
function FindWindow(C1, C2: PChar): Longint; external 'FindWindowA@user32.dll stdcall';
function GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd: Longint; opt: Word): Word; external 'GetWindowThreadProcessId@user32.dll stdcall';
function OpenProcess(dwDesiredAccess: Word; inherit: Byte; pid: Word): Longint; external 'OpenProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function GetProcessId(proc: Longint): Word; external 'GetProcessId@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function GetLastError(): Word; external 'GetLastError@kernel32.dll stdcall';
var
res, err: Word;
wnd, proc: Longint;
Begin
wnd := Findwindow('', search_window);
if (wnd > 0) then
begin
res := GetWindowThreadProcessId(wnd, res);
proc := OpenProcess($0400,0,res);
err := GetLastError();
writeln(IntToStr(proc));
writeln(IntToStr(err));
end;
End.
```

Im trying to use LongWord and Cardinal, but i have the same error.. Who can help me?)
P.S. its not delphi.. i dont know what is this :) Programm calls UOScript

Comment: If this is Delphi then these API functions are already (properly) declared in the Windows unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenProcess has declaration

```
HANDLE WINAPI OpenProcess(
  _In_  DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
  _In_  BOOL bInheritHandle,
  _In_  DWORD dwProcessId
);
```

`dwDesiredAccess` and `pid` are double words that are

```
typedef unsigned long       DWORD;
```

i.e. 32bit on x86, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419/visual-c-how-large-is-a-dword-with-32-and-64-bit-code) answer.

But Delphi/Pascal [`Word`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=DataTypes) type is 16bit.

Also, `BOOL` is [defined as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
typedef int BOOL;
```

So, you should use Integer for `inherit` instead of `Byte`

So, your function declaration is incorrect.

Seems you should use `Cardinal` or `LongWord` instead of `Word` in your declarations.

If you use Delphi, you can import `Windows` module that has all Win API functions defined.

Comment: thx. but how can i declare that function on pascal? What type i should use?

Comment: Word is Borland (Turbo/Delphi Pascal) style. Original Pascal has only one signed integer and uses subranges for the rest