# Not sure how to marshal a DWORD constant from the Dism API in C#

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm very new to Windows programming and C#, so hopefully I'm asking this question the right way. I'm trying to put a C# wrapper around the C++ Dism API for Windows, but I'm not sure how to marshal a DWORD constant (aside from this, I've managed to figure out marshaling and p/invoke for the most part).

Basically the "DismCommitFunction" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh825835.aspx has a signature which requires a DWORD constant. The constant names are defined on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh824739.aspx but there are no values.

The example in C++ (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh824804.aspx) just seems to use the constants, but I'm not sure how to do this in C#.

Do I need to know the values of these constants, or can I get them from the Dism API header?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you need to know the values.  Yes, you get them from the api header.  The cleanest way is to declare them as an enum.

Comment: Thanks Hans! That has solved my problem - I just needed to look at the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

A DWORD is basically an `int` in C#.

See [How large is a DWORD with 32- and 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419/visual-c-how-large-is-a-dword-with-32-and-64-bit-code) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

VC++ DWORD is an System.UInt32 in C#